# May I sync users/groups from Active Directory though SCIM (or any protocol)

Tags: active-directory, scim

I found it's possible to sync users/groups from Azure AD to local App though SCIM. But it seems not available in local AD, and seems not available in ADFS.

How I can sync from local AD, or is there any tools I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a [SCIM Product](http://www.simplecloud.info/#implementations) which you can create yourself or Purchase from several vendors.

Assuming you wish to take entries out of your local Microsoft Active Directory and "SCIM Them" into something else, you would probably want a SCIM Client and then put them into your SCIM Service Provider.

You would need to use something to get the entries out of Microsoft Active Directory and then use SCIM to put them into ???.

You could also use the [Microsoft DirSync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223347.aspx) Control using LDAP

There are many IDM vendors that create product with this functionality.

Comment: Shameless plug. The [PingDataSync Server](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/products/pingdatasync-server.html) is one of those implementations.

Comment: A solution I was thinking about is to use the plugin to sync to Azure AD, and create an app in Azure AD and sync all users from there to your SCIM service, using Azure's automated provisioning.that way you can leverage the Maturity of this services.
Can anyone tell from his experience what he thinks about it?

Comment: To sync with Azure, you probably should look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/whatis-hybrid-identity